# How to make a POST API call with many (50+) fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a fairly large API call to make with all the info on a form.

I can't seem to figure out the best way to go about sending the serialized data to the API endpoint.

1. I could put all my fields into an object in javascript, and pass it
2. I could take the model the is submitted by the controller, and pass it to the end point

I'm not really sure how to do either.

Comment: Have a look at `serialize()` - it should do just what you need... https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I can serialize the whole form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery has a built-in method to make this easy.

```
$.post("/somepage.asp",$("#theform").serialize()).done(function(){
    // done!
}).fail(function() {
    // something went wrong!
});
```

it will serialize all of the form fields in the form and post them to the page of your choice.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
http://api.jquery.com/serialze/
http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/

Comment: yep! exactly what I was looking for